# How to create a page with a structure like this?

Tags: tables

How to create a page with a structure like this? Will there be appropriate to use the table if I need to have all of page like this?
[image: page]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Can you show use what you've tried?  I would also reconsider censoring the document, unless it's absolutely necessary.  It will give us a much better idea of what you want to do.

Comment: @SeanAllred I hid text because it is not so important

Comment: If you show the text, it will give us some context for your document and prompt a good syntax.  As it stands, this looks like something done in `tabular`, except it's *definitely* not a table.

Comment: You could do it with minipage, \parbox and \fbox, but it would probably be easier to do it as a tikzpicture.  Do you know the heights, or do they depend on content?  And if multiple pages are like this (precisely) you might try flowfram.

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with sample content would make it a lot easier for people to help. If you can't post the actual content, don't. Any dummy text will do if it is similar in terms of quantity and approximate word lengths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a tikzpicture solution:

[image: full page]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\innersep}
\newlength{\cellheight}
\newlength{\leftwidth}
\newlength{\rightwidth}
\newlength{\topheight}
\newlength{\middleheight}
\newlength{\bottomheight}

\setlength{\innersep}{.3em}
\setlength{\cellheight}{\dimexpr 0.1666\textheight-2\innersep}
\setlength{\leftwidth}{\dimexpr 2in-2\innersep}
\setlength{\rightwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\leftwidth-4\innersep}
\setlength{\topheight}{\dimexpr 2in-2\innersep}
\setlength{\middleheight}{\dimexpr 0.5\textheight-\topheight-4\innersep}
\setlength{\bottomheight}{\dimexpr 0.5\textheight-2\innersep}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-13.2pt}% first page only
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,inner sep=\innersep}]
\path (0,0) node(A){\parbox[t][\cellheight]{\leftwidth}{ cell A }}
  node[below] (B) at (A.south) {\parbox[t][\cellheight]{\leftwidth}{ cell B }}
  node[below] (C) at (B.south) {\parbox[t][\cellheight]{\leftwidth}{ cell C}}
  node[below] (D) at (C.south) {\parbox[t][\cellheight]{\leftwidth}{ cell D }}
  node[below] (E) at (D.south) {\parbox[t][\cellheight]{\leftwidth}{ cell E }}
  node[below] (F) at (E.south) {\parbox[t][\cellheight]{\leftwidth}{ cell F }}
  node[below right] (G) at (A.north east) {\parbox[t][\topheight]{\rightwidth}{ cell G }}
  node[above right] (H) at (C.south east) {\parbox[t][\middleheight]{\rightwidth}{ cell H }}
  node[below right] (I) at (D.north east) {\parbox[t][\bottomheight]{\rightwidth}{ cell I }};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

In Plain Tex:

```
\hsize=480  pt 
\vsize=700  pt   

\newdimen\temp


\def\fmt{\leftskip2pt\rightskip2pt\abovedisplayskip0pt
\belowdisplayskip0pt}



\long\def\btab#1#2#3{\vbox to #1pt{\fmt\hsize=#2pt\advance\hsize by
-.8pt\temp=#1pt\advance\temp by -.8pt%
                      \hrule\hbox to #2 pt{\vrule\hfill
                                                 \vbox to\temp{\hbox to\hsize{\hfill\vbox{#3}\hfill}
\vfil}\hfill\vrule}\vfil\hrule}}        

\long\def\Boxit#1#2{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\vrule\vbox spread#1pt{\vfil
                     \hbox spread#1pt{\hfil#2\hfil}\vfil}\vrule}\hrule}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\Boxit{0}{% 
\noindent
\vbox{
\btab{100}{100}{\vskip1pt \noindent stuff}\nointerlineskip
\btab{100}{100}{stuff}\nointerlineskip
\btab{100}{100}{stuff}\nointerlineskip
\btab{100}{100}{stuff}\nointerlineskip
\btab{100}{100}{stuff}\nointerlineskip
\btab{100}{100}{stuff} \nointerlineskip
\btab{100}{100}{stuff}}%
\vbox{ 
\btab{200}{380}{\noindent stuff}  \nointerlineskip
\btab{150}{380}{stuff}\nointerlineskip
\btab{350}{380}{stuff}}}


\bye
```

The Boxit macro wraps all the boxes in a ruled box (so the outer rules are the same thickness as the inner).

[image]
(Suggestions for improvements are welcome.)